# in which format should I expect newlines in a submitted textarea

Tags: php, forms, http, newline

My PHP web app receives a form with a textarea where the user *is* expected to add newlines.
I than want to break the text into lines.

In which format should I expect the newlines in the submitted $_POST?
I know that in different environments it can be any of \n, \r, \n\r, \r\n , but what applies to the web? Do browsers, webserver (Apache in my case), or PHP normalize this somehow?

I don't want to do any assumptions about the users browser, and I do know that the text will be actually a spreadsheet cut and pasted from Excel.

(The design of this UI is not in my control)

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` instead

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, `PHP_EOL` is dependent on the platform PHP is running on – this question is about newlines transmitted from the client.

Comment: The question is: what are you going to do with this data?

Comment: _“In which format should I expect the newlines in the submitted $_POST?”_ – in possibly _any_ of the formats you mentioned. Use a regular expression to normalize these to `\n` before you continue to work with the data.

Comment: Sectus, I am going to parse it and infer logic. I want to know about any place where the user saw a newline when looking at his form, or any line present in a text he cut and pasted into the form from wherever

Comment: I would guess there's a standard in the HTML protocol for how form data should be encoded (not sure off the top of my head what it is, search for it), but that doesn't mean people can't send anything else as well, bypassing the browser.

Comment: @shealtiel you can use `preg_replace()` to replace all `\r\n`,`\n\r`,`\r` to `\n` ::: `$str = "Hello \r\n World";
$replaced = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n?\r/s", "\n", $str);`

Comment: @CBroe, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

> In which format should I expect the newlines in the submitted $_POST?

In possibly any of the formats you mentioned. You have no control over what the client sends you – and depending on browser/platform/factor X newlines might arrive in any possible form.

Use a regular expression to normalize these to \n before you continue to work with the data.

Edit:

As @deceze said, this is specified in the HTML5 spec as follows, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element:

> *“When a textarea is mutable, its raw value should be editable by the user: the user agent should allow the user to edit, insert, and remove text, and to insert and remove line breaks in the form of "LF" (U+000A) characters.”*

I don’t know whether this was specified in HTML 4.01 before – however, expecting any possible newline chars or char combination and normalizing it before working with the data is the secure way to go.

Comment: Thank you, and, does this look correct? $rows  = preg_split('/(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)/', $_POST['my_textarea'])